# Как сверстать такой текстовый блок?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Материалы:

Первая картинка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вторая картинка: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**SVG:**

```
<svg width="420" height="101" viewBox="0 0 420 101" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M7.96417 98.7456C7.71134 98.6436 7.42412 98.763 7.31742 99.0125C4.56561 97.7654 2.36944 95.5095 1.19661 92.7253C1.44888 92.6253 1.57594 92.3414 1.48074 92.0859C0.939976 90.6348 0.684691 89.0463 0.783623 87.3892L1.15944 81.0942C1.1759 80.8186 0.965782 80.5818 0.69013 80.5653L1.38218 68.9735C1.65783 68.99 1.89463 68.7799 1.91109 68.5042L2.66273 55.9142C2.67919 55.6385 2.46907 55.4017 2.19342 55.3853L2.88546 43.7935C3.16112 43.8099 3.39792 43.5998 3.41437 43.3242L4.16602 30.7341C4.18247 30.4585 3.97235 30.2217 3.6967 30.2052L4.38875 18.6134C4.6644 18.6299 4.9012 18.4198 4.91766 18.1441L5.29348 11.8491C5.38561 10.306 5.7779 8.85254 6.41007 7.54174C6.5285 7.29616 6.42824 7.0017 6.18629 6.87883C7.50935 4.4059 9.66889 2.46368 12.2678 1.40935C12.3644 1.66293 12.6466 1.79375 12.9033 1.70193C14.2736 1.21181 15.7604 0.975308 17.3046 1.04676L22.744 1.29846C23.0198 1.31122 23.2538 1.09795 23.2665 0.822102L33.1463 1.27926C33.1335 1.55511 33.3468 1.78908 33.6227 1.80184L44.5014 2.30523C44.7772 2.31799 45.0112 2.10472 45.0239 1.82887L54.9037 2.28603C54.891 2.56188 55.1042 2.79585 55.3801 2.80861L66.2588 3.312C66.5346 3.32476 66.7686 3.11149 66.7814 2.83564L76.6611 3.2928C76.6484 3.56865 76.8617 3.80262 77.1375 3.81538L88.0162 4.31877C88.2921 4.33153 88.526 4.11826 88.5388 3.84241L98.4186 4.29957C98.4058 4.57542 98.6191 4.80939 98.8949 4.82215L109.774 5.32554C110.049 5.3383 110.283 5.12503 110.296 4.84918L120.176 5.30634C120.163 5.58219 120.376 5.81616 120.652 5.82892L131.531 6.33231C131.807 6.34507 132.041 6.1318 132.054 5.85595L141.933 6.31311C141.921 6.58896 142.134 6.82293 142.41 6.83569L153.288 7.33908C153.564 7.35184 153.798 7.13857 153.811 6.86272L163.691 7.31988C163.678 7.59573 163.891 7.8297 164.167 7.84246L175.046 8.34585C175.322 8.35861 175.556 8.14534 175.568 7.86949L185.448 8.32665C185.435 8.6025 185.649 8.83647 185.925 8.84923L196.803 9.35262C197.079 9.36538 197.313 9.15211 197.326 8.87626L207.206 9.33342C207.193 9.60927 207.406 9.84324 207.682 9.856L218.561 10.3594C218.837 10.3721 219.071 10.1589 219.083 9.88303L228.963 10.3402C228.95 10.616 229.164 10.85 229.439 10.8628L240.318 11.3662C240.594 11.3789 240.828 11.1656 240.841 10.8898L250.72 11.347C250.708 11.6228 250.921 11.8568 251.197 11.8695L262.076 12.3729C262.351 12.3857 262.585 12.1724 262.598 11.8966L272.478 12.3537C272.465 12.6296 272.678 12.8635 272.954 12.8763L283.833 13.3797C284.109 13.3925 284.343 13.1792 284.356 12.9033L294.235 13.3605C294.223 13.6364 294.436 13.8703 294.712 13.8831L305.59 14.3865C305.866 14.3992 306.1 14.186 306.113 13.9101L315.993 14.3673C315.98 14.6431 316.193 14.8771 316.469 14.8899L327.348 15.3932C327.624 15.406 327.858 15.1927 327.87 14.9169L337.75 15.374C337.737 15.6499 337.951 15.8839 338.227 15.8966L349.105 16.4C349.381 16.4128 349.615 16.1995 349.628 15.9237L359.508 16.3808C359.495 16.6567 359.708 16.8906 359.984 16.9034L370.863 17.4068C371.139 17.4195 371.372 17.2063 371.385 16.9304L381.265 17.3876C381.252 17.6634 381.466 17.8974 381.741 17.9102L387.181 18.1619C388.245 18.2111 389.28 18.4064 390.263 18.7317C390.521 18.8173 390.801 18.6798 390.891 18.424C392.632 19.0821 394.198 20.1375 395.462 21.5042C395.259 21.6842 395.236 21.9944 395.412 22.2022C396.083 22.9908 396.652 23.877 397.097 24.8449L399.71 30.5261C399.825 30.777 400.122 30.8869 400.373 30.7715L405.18 41.2253C404.929 41.3407 404.82 41.6376 404.935 41.8885L410.16 53.2509C410.275 53.5018 410.572 53.6117 410.823 53.4963L415.63 63.9501C415.379 64.0655 415.27 64.3624 415.385 64.6133L417.997 70.2945C418.834 72.1141 419.153 73.9946 419.04 75.803C419.023 76.0751 419.227 76.3099 419.497 76.3324C419.116 79.9616 417.073 83.2685 413.998 85.2332C413.856 85.0014 413.555 84.9241 413.319 85.061C411.753 85.9711 409.928 86.5273 407.927 86.593L402.436 86.7732C402.161 86.7823 401.944 87.0134 401.953 87.2893L391.972 87.617C391.963 87.341 391.732 87.1246 391.456 87.1336L380.476 87.4941C380.2 87.5031 379.984 87.7342 379.993 88.0102L370.012 88.3378C370.003 88.0618 369.772 87.8454 369.496 87.8545L358.516 88.2149C358.24 88.224 358.023 88.4551 358.033 88.7311L348.052 89.0587C348.043 88.7827 347.812 88.5663 347.536 88.5753L336.555 88.9358C336.279 88.9448 336.063 89.1759 336.072 89.4519L326.091 89.7795C326.082 89.5035 325.851 89.2871 325.575 89.2962L314.595 89.6566C314.319 89.6657 314.103 89.8968 314.112 90.1728L304.131 90.5004C304.122 90.2244 303.891 90.008 303.615 90.0171L292.635 90.3775C292.359 90.3865 292.142 90.6176 292.151 90.8936L282.171 91.2212C282.162 90.9452 281.931 90.7289 281.655 90.7379L270.674 91.0983C270.398 91.1074 270.182 91.3385 270.191 91.6145L260.21 91.9421C260.201 91.6661 259.97 91.4497 259.694 91.4588L248.714 91.8192C248.438 91.8283 248.222 92.0593 248.231 92.3353L238.25 92.6629C238.241 92.387 238.01 92.1706 237.734 92.1796L226.754 92.5401C226.478 92.5491 226.261 92.7802 226.27 93.0562L216.29 93.3838C216.281 93.1078 216.05 92.8914 215.774 92.9005L204.793 93.2609C204.517 93.27 204.301 93.501 204.31 93.777L194.329 94.1047C194.32 93.8287 194.089 93.6123 193.813 93.6213L182.833 93.9818C182.557 93.9908 182.341 94.2219 182.35 94.4979L172.369 94.8255C172.36 94.5495 172.129 94.3331 171.853 94.3422L160.873 94.7026C160.597 94.7117 160.38 94.9428 160.389 95.2188L150.409 95.5464C150.4 95.2704 150.169 95.054 149.893 95.063L138.912 95.4235C138.636 95.4325 138.42 95.6636 138.429 95.9396L128.448 96.2672C128.439 95.9912 128.208 95.7748 127.932 95.7839L116.952 96.1443C116.676 96.1534 116.46 96.3845 116.469 96.6605L106.488 96.9881C106.479 96.7121 106.248 96.4957 105.972 96.5048L94.9918 96.8652C94.7158 96.8742 94.4994 97.1053 94.5084 97.3813L84.5277 97.7089C84.5187 97.4329 84.2876 97.2166 84.0116 97.2256L73.0314 97.586C72.7554 97.5951 72.539 97.8262 72.5481 98.1022L62.5674 98.4298C62.5583 98.1538 62.3272 97.9374 62.0512 97.9465L51.0711 98.3069C50.7951 98.316 50.5787 98.547 50.5877 98.823L40.6071 99.1507C40.598 98.8747 40.3669 98.6583 40.0909 98.6673L29.1107 99.0277C28.8348 99.0368 28.6184 99.2679 28.6274 99.5439L18.6467 99.8715C18.6376 99.5955 18.4066 99.3791 18.1306 99.3882L12.6405 99.5684C10.9813 99.6229 9.4003 99.3251 7.96417 98.7456Z" stroke="#FF1276" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="11 11"/>
</svg>
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
<div class="header__container">
<div class="header__row">
  <div class="header__column">
    <a href="#"><img class="header__logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo EduToys" /></a>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav__list">
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="" class="nav__link">Products<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 2</a></li>
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 3</a></li>
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 4</a></li>
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item">
          <a href="" class="nav__link">Resources<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 6</a></li>
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 7</a></li>
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 8</a></li>
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 9</a></li>
            <li class="submenu__item"><a class="submenu__link" href="">Item 0</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav__item"><a href="" class="nav__link">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="header__auth auth-header">
    <button class="auth-header__login-btn">Log In</button>
    <button class="auth-header__sign-up-btn">Sign up</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="header__content">
  <div class="header__text">
    <div class="header__bg">
    <h1 class="header__title"><span class="purple">Fun to care,</span> <span class="orange">Comfy Feel</span></h1>
    <p class="header__desc">Mauris aliquet enim quis odio lacinia, id viverra elit convallis. Nunc nulla massa elit</p>
    <button class="header__btn">Shop now</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="header__image">
    <img src="images/hero.png" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.header {
  margin-bottom: 76px;
  &__row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;

    margin-bottom: 68px;
    padding: 40px 0 0;
  }
  &__column {
    display: flex;
    gap: 30px;
    align-items: center;
  }
  &__logo {
    max-width: 90px;
    max-height: 48px;
  }
  &__auth {
    display: flex;
    gap: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #667085;

    button {
      font-weight: 500;
    }
  }
  &__content {
    display: flex;
  }
  &__text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  &__bg {
    max-width: 427px;
    max-height: 100px;
    background-image: url("../images/border.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 3px 0 0 30px;
  }

  &__title {
    max-width: 427px;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.5;

    .purple {
      max-width: 427px;
      max-height: 105px;
      position: relative;
      color: #ff1276;

      &:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: -30px;
        right: -60px;
        width: 104px;
        height: 105px;
        background: url("../images/2.png");
      }
    }

    .orange {
      font-weight: 900;
      color: #fba628;
    }
  }
  &__desc {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    color: #959595;
  }
  &__image {
  }
  &__btn {
    max-width: 157px;
    padding: 16px 28px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #ff1276;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
}

.auth-header__login-btn {
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background: transparent;
}

.auth-header__sign-up-btn {
  padding: 14px 22px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #7f56d9;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.nav {
  font-weight: 500;
  &__list {
    display: flex;
    gap: 36px;
  }
  &__item {
    &:hover .submenu {
      height: 300px;

      transition: height 0.5s ease;
    }
  }
  &__link {
    color: #667085;
    &:hover {
      color: pink;
    }
  }
  a {
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  transition: height 0.5s ease;

  &__item {
    position: relative;
  }
  &__link {
    display: flex;
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня вышло так.
Ключевые свойства для позиционирования:
`position: relative`, `position: absolute`, `top:`, `left:`, `transform: rotate(-10deg)`, `z-index: 1`.

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 550px;
  height: 420px;
}

.border {
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  top: 60px;
  left: 70px;
}

.horse {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 400px;
}

.pyramid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 0;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.purple {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 105px;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-10deg);
  color: #ff1276;
}

.orange {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  font-size: 56px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fba628;
}

.desc {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 380px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  top: 250px;
  left: 105px;
  color: #959595;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 105px;
  padding: 16px 28px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #ff1276;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <svg class="border" width="420" height="101" viewBox="0 0 420 101" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M7.96417 98.7456C7.71134 98.6436 7.42412 98.763 7.31742 99.0125C4.56561 97.7654 2.36944 95.5095 1.19661 92.7253C1.44888 92.6253 1.57594 92.3414 1.48074 92.0859C0.939976 90.6348 0.684691 89.0463 0.783623 87.3892L1.15944 81.0942C1.1759 80.8186 0.965782 80.5818 0.69013 80.5653L1.38218 68.9735C1.65783 68.99 1.89463 68.7799 1.91109 68.5042L2.66273 55.9142C2.67919 55.6385 2.46907 55.4017 2.19342 55.3853L2.88546 43.7935C3.16112 43.8099 3.39792 43.5998 3.41437 43.3242L4.16602 30.7341C4.18247 30.4585 3.97235 30.2217 3.6967 30.2052L4.38875 18.6134C4.6644 18.6299 4.9012 18.4198 4.91766 18.1441L5.29348 11.8491C5.38561 10.306 5.7779 8.85254 6.41007 7.54174C6.5285 7.29616 6.42824 7.0017 6.18629 6.87883C7.50935 4.4059 9.66889 2.46368 12.2678 1.40935C12.3644 1.66293 12.6466 1.79375 12.9033 1.70193C14.2736 1.21181 15.7604 0.975308 17.3046 1.04676L22.744 1.29846C23.0198 1.31122 23.2538 1.09795 23.2665 0.822102L33.1463 1.27926C33.1335 1.55511 33.3468 1.78908 33.6227 1.80184L44.5014 2.30523C44.7772 2.31799 45.0112 2.10472 45.0239 1.82887L54.9037 2.28603C54.891 2.56188 55.1042 2.79585 55.3801 2.80861L66.2588 3.312C66.5346 3.32476 66.7686 3.11149 66.7814 2.83564L76.6611 3.2928C76.6484 3.56865 76.8617 3.80262 77.1375 3.81538L88.0162 4.31877C88.2921 4.33153 88.526 4.11826 88.5388 3.84241L98.4186 4.29957C98.4058 4.57542 98.6191 4.80939 98.8949 4.82215L109.774 5.32554C110.049 5.3383 110.283 5.12503 110.296 4.84918L120.176 5.30634C120.163 5.58219 120.376 5.81616 120.652 5.82892L131.531 6.33231C131.807 6.34507 132.041 6.1318 132.054 5.85595L141.933 6.31311C141.921 6.58896 142.134 6.82293 142.41 6.83569L153.288 7.33908C153.564 7.35184 153.798 7.13857 153.811 6.86272L163.691 7.31988C163.678 7.59573 163.891 7.8297 164.167 7.84246L175.046 8.34585C175.322 8.35861 175.556 8.14534 175.568 7.86949L185.448 8.32665C185.435 8.6025 185.649 8.83647 185.925 8.84923L196.803 9.35262C197.079 9.36538 197.313 9.15211 197.326 8.87626L207.206 9.33342C207.193 9.60927 207.406 9.84324 207.682 9.856L218.561 10.3594C218.837 10.3721 219.071 10.1589 219.083 9.88303L228.963 10.3402C228.95 10.616 229.164 10.85 229.439 10.8628L240.318 11.3662C240.594 11.3789 240.828 11.1656 240.841 10.8898L250.72 11.347C250.708 11.6228 250.921 11.8568 251.197 11.8695L262.076 12.3729C262.351 12.3857 262.585 12.1724 262.598 11.8966L272.478 12.3537C272.465 12.6296 272.678 12.8635 272.954 12.8763L283.833 13.3797C284.109 13.3925 284.343 13.1792 284.356 12.9033L294.235 13.3605C294.223 13.6364 294.436 13.8703 294.712 13.8831L305.59 14.3865C305.866 14.3992 306.1 14.186 306.113 13.9101L315.993 14.3673C315.98 14.6431 316.193 14.8771 316.469 14.8899L327.348 15.3932C327.624 15.406 327.858 15.1927 327.87 14.9169L337.75 15.374C337.737 15.6499 337.951 15.8839 338.227 15.8966L349.105 16.4C349.381 16.4128 349.615 16.1995 349.628 15.9237L359.508 16.3808C359.495 16.6567 359.708 16.8906 359.984 16.9034L370.863 17.4068C371.139 17.4195 371.372 17.2063 371.385 16.9304L381.265 17.3876C381.252 17.6634 381.466 17.8974 381.741 17.9102L387.181 18.1619C388.245 18.2111 389.28 18.4064 390.263 18.7317C390.521 18.8173 390.801 18.6798 390.891 18.424C392.632 19.0821 394.198 20.1375 395.462 21.5042C395.259 21.6842 395.236 21.9944 395.412 22.2022C396.083 22.9908 396.652 23.877 397.097 24.8449L399.71 30.5261C399.825 30.777 400.122 30.8869 400.373 30.7715L405.18 41.2253C404.929 41.3407 404.82 41.6376 404.935 41.8885L410.16 53.2509C410.275 53.5018 410.572 53.6117 410.823 53.4963L415.63 63.9501C415.379 64.0655 415.27 64.3624 415.385 64.6133L417.997 70.2945C418.834 72.1141 419.153 73.9946 419.04 75.803C419.023 76.0751 419.227 76.3099 419.497 76.3324C419.116 79.9616 417.073 83.2685 413.998 85.2332C413.856 85.0014 413.555 84.9241 413.319 85.061C411.753 85.9711 409.928 86.5273 407.927 86.593L402.436 86.7732C402.161 86.7823 401.944 87.0134 401.953 87.2893L391.972 87.617C391.963 87.341 391.732 87.1246 391.456 87.1336L380.476 87.4941C380.2 87.5031 379.984 87.7342 379.993 88.0102L370.012 88.3378C370.003 88.0618 369.772 87.8454 369.496 87.8545L358.516 88.2149C358.24 88.224 358.023 88.4551 358.033 88.7311L348.052 89.0587C348.043 88.7827 347.812 88.5663 347.536 88.5753L336.555 88.9358C336.279 88.9448 336.063 89.1759 336.072 89.4519L326.091 89.7795C326.082 89.5035 325.851 89.2871 325.575 89.2962L314.595 89.6566C314.319 89.6657 314.103 89.8968 314.112 90.1728L304.131 90.5004C304.122 90.2244 303.891 90.008 303.615 90.0171L292.635 90.3775C292.359 90.3865 292.142 90.6176 292.151 90.8936L282.171 91.2212C282.162 90.9452 281.931 90.7289 281.655 90.7379L270.674 91.0983C270.398 91.1074 270.182 91.3385 270.191 91.6145L260.21 91.9421C260.201 91.6661 259.97 91.4497 259.694 91.4588L248.714 91.8192C248.438 91.8283 248.222 92.0593 248.231 92.3353L238.25 92.6629C238.241 92.387 238.01 92.1706 237.734 92.1796L226.754 92.5401C226.478 92.5491 226.261 92.7802 226.27 93.0562L216.29 93.3838C216.281 93.1078 216.05 92.8914 215.774 92.9005L204.793 93.2609C204.517 93.27 204.301 93.501 204.31 93.777L194.329 94.1047C194.32 93.8287 194.089 93.6123 193.813 93.6213L182.833 93.9818C182.557 93.9908 182.341 94.2219 182.35 94.4979L172.369 94.8255C172.36 94.5495 172.129 94.3331 171.853 94.3422L160.873 94.7026C160.597 94.7117 160.38 94.9428 160.389 95.2188L150.409 95.5464C150.4 95.2704 150.169 95.054 149.893 95.063L138.912 95.4235C138.636 95.4325 138.42 95.6636 138.429 95.9396L128.448 96.2672C128.439 95.9912 128.208 95.7748 127.932 95.7839L116.952 96.1443C116.676 96.1534 116.46 96.3845 116.469 96.6605L106.488 96.9881C106.479 96.7121 106.248 96.4957 105.972 96.5048L94.9918 96.8652C94.7158 96.8742 94.4994 97.1053 94.5084 97.3813L84.5277 97.7089C84.5187 97.4329 84.2876 97.2166 84.0116 97.2256L73.0314 97.586C72.7554 97.5951 72.539 97.8262 72.5481 98.1022L62.5674 98.4298C62.5583 98.1538 62.3272 97.9374 62.0512 97.9465L51.0711 98.3069C50.7951 98.316 50.5787 98.547 50.5877 98.823L40.6071 99.1507C40.598 98.8747 40.3669 98.6583 40.0909 98.6673L29.1107 99.0277C28.8348 99.0368 28.6184 99.2679 28.6274 99.5439L18.6467 99.8715C18.6376 99.5955 18.4066 99.3791 18.1306 99.3882L12.6405 99.5684C10.9813 99.6229 9.4003 99.3251 7.96417 98.7456Z" stroke="#FF1276" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="11 11"/>
      </svg>
  <img class="horse" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RMJa.png" alt="">
  <img class="pyramid" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW1Nc.png" alt="">
  <h1 class="title">
    <span class="purple">Fun to care,</span>
    <span class="orange">Comfy Feel</span>
  </h1>
  <p class="desc">Mauris aliquet enim quis odio lacinia, id viverra elit convallis. Nunc nulla massa elit</p>
  <button class="btn">Shop now</button>
</div>
```

я ваш код малость проредила, оставила только этот конкретный блок и удалила лишнее. Изменила некоторые размеры, чтобы результат больше соответствовал макету. Надеюсь, сможете сопоставить, что было у вас и что стало у меня.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Уточни, в вёрстке чего тебе нужна помощь

Заголовок Fun to care:

```
.purple {
        max-width: 427px;
        max-height: 105px;
        position: relative;
        color: #ff1276;
        transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -15deg) skewY(-2deg);
        border: 4px dashed yellow;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
```